# thread 'main' panicked at 'Box<Any>'

Tags: rust

I am trying to learn Rust. I am following a book [online](https://chikoski.info/rust-handson/?locale=en-US#/24/6) which implements the unix program `cat`. Right now I trying to read the content of files passed as an argument like that `cargo run file1.txt file2.txt` but the program panics:

```
D:\rust\cat> cargo run .\src\test.txt
   Compiling cat v0.1.0 (D:\rust\cat)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.62s
     Running `target\debug\cat.exe .\src\test.txt`
thread 'main' panicked at 'Box<Any>', src\main.rs:12:28
```

this is my program:

```
use std::env;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    if args.len() > 1 {
        match read_file(&args) {
            Ok(content) => println!("{}", content),
            Err(reason) => panic!(reason),
        }
    }
}

fn read_file(filenames: &Vec<String>) -> Result<String, io::Error> {
    let mut content = String::new();

    for filename in filenames {
        let mut file = File::open(filename)?;
        file.read_to_string(&mut content)?;
    }

    Ok(content)
}
```

Can anyone explain what I am missing here?

Comment: Not related, but you don't need to collect the iterator: https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=639bee013865eb9dc5c9987f378f5816

Comment: I cannot get why there is this message, but you shouldn't panic by yourself, use `unwrap` or the error propagation: https://play.integer32.com/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=31767ffd4bd86b62548afd00b919a067

Comment: @Boiethios thanks! Will try that. I used panic! as the book uses that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first element of the `Args` iterator returned by `std::env::args` is tipically the path of executable (see the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.args.html)
for more details).

The error arises because you do not skip the first arg: the program binary is not a sequence of valid UTF-8 bytes.

The apparently non sense error `thread 'main' panicked at 'Box<Any>'` is because `panic!` is not used with the same arguments of 
the `format!` syntax.

```
use std::env;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    for filename in env::args().skip(1) {
        match read_file(filename) {
            Ok(content) => println!("{}", content),
            Err(reason) => panic!("{}", reason),
        }
    }
}

fn read_file(filename: String) -> Result<String, io::Error> {
    let mut content = String::new();

    let mut file = File::open(filename)?;
    file.read_to_string(&mut content)?;

    Ok(content)
}
```

Comment: Right, I was not aware that the first argument is the executable itself. Thank you for pointing out that